# How to Change Local Security Policy using .NET

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, local-security-policy

I have read too many topics about reading from Local Security Policy, but I need to change its values, spesifically "Audit system events".

How to do that using .NET environment..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved the problem, by running this command in the command line `cmd.exe`:

```
Auditpol /set /category:system /success:enable /failure:disable
```

in order to do that I saved it in a `.bat` file and run it as administrator.